# Push failed: remote: error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:

Tags: git

Помогите решить проблему при заливке изменений на сервер (Push на Git).
Выскакивает следующее сообщение:

```
Push failed: remote: error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
```

При этом изменения видны другими пользователями и они их могут загрузить (pull). Но этот файл на сервере не переписывается (крутится его старая версия), хотя я уже несколько раз забрасывал новый файл.

Comment: выполните `$ git pull` (подозреваю, что возникнут конфликты, которые надо будет разрешить), а уже затем — `$ git push`.

Comment: Сообщение довольно странное. На ремоуте имеются изменения (незакоммиченные) в рабочем дереве? В каком виде удалённый репозторий?

Comment: Спасибо, всем. админ всё исправил.